# WSL with VS Code and python 3.5

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, python-3.5, vscode-debugger

I want to use VS Code with wsl and a specific python (version 3.5.0).
I managed to install the desired python version following this instruction
https://www.scriptinghouse.com/2023/11/install-specific-python-version-on-windows-subsystem-for-linux-wsl.html.
It worked and the python 3.5.0 Interpreter appears in VS Code.
But my problem now is that the 'python debugger doesn't support any versions below 3.7'.
The first time I tried there was a warning saying this and now nothing happens when I try to run a simple test script:

```
print('test')
```

Does anybody have an idea how to make this work?

Comment: You may need to install an old version of the Python extension in VSCode, by clicking the dropdown next to the Uninstall button and choosing `Install Another Version.`   From the changelog, the last version to support Python 3.5 was `2020.8.x`.  Note that this may cause you to lose support for Python 3.10 or later

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. I tried this but somehow I am only able to downgrade the python extension but not the python debugger.  If I look for other versions in the Python debugger extension , there is no other available. This way I am still not able to run my script with the python 3.5.0 Interpreter. If I downgrade the python extension and try to run my script VS Code says ''Install additional Debuggers'.

Comment: Based on [the README file for the extension](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python-debugger/blob/main/README.md#limited-support-for-deprecated-python-versions), you may need to enable pre-release versions on the Debugger extension in order to install past versions, and it seemed to make the option available to me.  Then you'll need to install a `2023.1.x` version of the debugging extension.  If that works for you let me know and I'll write it up as a formal answer to be accepted.  I didn't do that initially as I don't currently have the WSL configuration set up to test it myself.

Comment: Hey, thank you so much. I was able to install it but debugging still doesn't work. I get the error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'resolveEnvironment')" using the debugger v2023.1.11801008.
I can run my script using the terminal but there must be some issues with the Debugger.

Answer (score 0):

You could read [document about vscode-python-debugger](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python-debugger?tab=readme-ov-file#limited-support-for-deprecated-python-versions).

Older versions of the Python Debugger extension are available for debugging Python projects that use outdated Python versions like Python 2.7 and Python 3.6. However, it’s important to note that our team is no longer maintaining these extension versions. We strongly advise you to update your project to a supported Python version if possible.

You can reference the table below to find the most recent Python Debugger extension version that offers debugging support for projects using deprecated Python versions, as well as the debugpy version that is shipped in each extension version. If you do not see older extension versions to install (<=2024.0.0), try opting-in to pre-releases. You can do so on the extension page by clicking `Switch to Pre-Release` Version.

| Python version | Latest supported Python Debugger extension version | debugpy version |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2.7, >= 3.5 | 2023.1.XXX | 1.5.1 |
| >= 3.7 | 2023.3.XXX | 1.7.0 |

You could click **install another version** and choose 2023.1.xx:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hey, thank you so much. I was able to install it but debugging still doesn't work. I get the error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'resolveEnvironment')" using the debugger v2023.1.11801008. I can run my script using the terminal but there must be some issues with the Debugger.